# Django image uploading

Tags: python, django, image, upload

I have a problem with image uploading. For now, chosen image file is not copied to destination directory and path to this file is not added to database.

I'm giving my code below:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to="avatar/")
```

form.py

```
class ProfileEditionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ('user')
```

view.py:

```
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)

        if request.method == "POST":
            form = ProfileEditionForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)

            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile_edit'))
        else:
            form = ProfileEditionForm(instance=user)

        return direct_to_template(request, 'profile_edit.html', { 'form' : form })
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main_page'))
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Yes. `MEDIA_ROOT = 'webroot'`

Comment: But it's not absolute, should be: /home/user/project/webroot

Comment: from where this `/home/user/project` from?

Comment: where is you project located? /path/to/project if on linux windows: D:\path\to\project

Comment: And, i think, this path is correct, because css's in that webroot directory works. So... is path ok?

Comment: Well, i have change it, but, still, don't want to upload that image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your ModelForm is bound to UserProfile model, but your are instantiating it with instance=user.

PS: request.user is User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/

your form should have the enctype="multipart/form-data" or request.FILES won't have any data stream associated

Comment: Yes, my form have that enctype.