# 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, media

I'm having trouble getting images to upload to an S3 bucket from Django

The error I'm getting is:

> 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'get'

I've looked at similar questions, but haven't found a solution from them (or others not listed below):

[ModelForm has no attribute get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445812/modelform-has-no-attribute-get)

[Django image uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241743/django-image-uploading?rq=1)

[django 'User' object has no attribute 'get' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28336247/django-user-object-has-no-attribute-get-error)

Here's my code:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import UploadImage, UploadAudio

class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = UploadImage
    fields = ['myimage']
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .forms import ImageForm, AudioForm
from .models import UploadImage


def ImageCreate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES['myimage'])
        if form.is_valid():
            image = form.save(commit=False)
            image.author = request.user
            image.save()
            messages.success(request, "Uploaded successfully")
            return redirect('mytimer')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Unable to upload at this time")
else:
    form = ImageForm()
return render(request, "myimages.html", {'form': form})
```

**models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class UploadImage(models.Model):
    """
    Define how the user will upload images
    """
    # link author to registered user
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    myimage = models.ImageField(upload_to='myimages/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Thank you so much in advance for any help.

**traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/myimages/

Django Version: 1.11.6
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'hello',
'timer',
'accounts',
'django_forms_bootstrap',
'diary',
'storages',
'useruploads',
'debug_toolbar']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File 
"/home/pauly/Documents/MeditationTimer/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
41.             response = get_response(request)

File 
"/home/pauly/Documents/MeditationTimer/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
187.                 response = 
self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, 
request)

File 
"/home/pauly/Documents/MeditationTimer/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, 
*callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/pauly/Documents/MeditationTimer/Meditate_prj/
useruploads/views.py" in ImageCreate
15.         if form.is_valid():

File 
"/home/pauly/Documents/MeditationTimer/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
183.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File 
"/home/pauly/Documents/MeditationTimer/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
175.             self.full_clean()

File 
"/home/pauly/Documents/MeditationTimer/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
384.         self._clean_fields()

File 
"/home/pauly/Documents/MeditationTimer/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_fields
396.                 value = 
field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, 
self.add_prefix(name))

File 
"/home/pauly/Documents/MeditationTimer/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in value_from_datadict
423.         upload = super(ClearableFileInput, 
self).value_from_datadict(data, files, name)

File 
"/home/pauly/Documents/MeditationTimer/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in value_from_datadict
367.         return files.get(name)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /myimages/
Exception Value: 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Do you have a full traceback?  Looking at the traceback will usually point you much more quickly in the right direction.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any code here relating to uploading to S3.

Comment: I don't think the problem really occurs anywhere directly related to S3 but again that's why we'd need to see the *full* traceback.

Comment: Full traceback in comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't pass a specific file from the request to the form, you should pass the whole FILES dictionary just as you pass the whole POST.

```
form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```